# Store code i mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql, twitter-bootstrap

I am making a database on bootstrap code. I have made a database named bootstrap and I have a table named classes. There is a column in that table is named sample and the datatype is tinytext.

When I try to store:

```
<li class="active"><a href="Jumbotron.html">Profile</a></li>
```

Then display it with:

```
<td><?php $str = $row['exsample']; echo wordwrap($str,25,"<br>\n")?></td>
```

What is displayed is:

```
href="Jumbotron.html">Profile
```

I am sure it is because of the < and " in the string.

What datatype should I use so the the whole string is displayed?

Comment: Why do you want to insert hard line breaks in your HTML?

Comment: Did you give up or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't `wordwrap()` HTML and put a `<br>` in there because it's impossible to tell where that will happen.  Your code yields this (view the source of the browser output):

```
<td><li class="active"><a<br>
href="Jumbotron.html">Profile</a></li></td>
```

Because it is inserting a `<br>` right after the `<a` breaking the HTML.

You might want to look at [How do you parse and process HTML/XML in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php) or one of the Related links, then parse out the text from the HTML and `wordwrap()` the text.

Comment: This is correct. Whatever, it isn't clear why anyone would want to add hard line breaks at random spots when we are printing HTML.